# Rails: Using Eval to call another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, controllers, realex-payments-api

I know calling other actions from the controller isn't approved, but code I've got is using eval() to do exactly that.

```
  if @payment.save
    eval("pay_with_#{params[:method]}")
  end
```

the method parameter is set (its value is realex) and the payment is saving, yet the pay_with_realex function isn't being called. Is this presumably to do with eval()??

What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: This is such a wrong way to even attempt.  Just make a private function and call it from both actions.   Avoid eval unless you are a ruby meta-wizard.

Comment: yeah thats what i felt, so I need another way

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Object.send`

```
if @payment.save
    send("pay_with_#{params[:method]}")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your controller, my initial thought would be to move "pay_with_" methods down into whatever your @payment class is and subclass it to handle the different payment methods.

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class PaymentRealEx < Payment
  def pay
    # your way of doing payment
  end
end

class PaymentController
  def create
    case params[:method]
    when "realex"
      @payment = PaymentReadEx.new
    end
    if @payment.save
      @payment.pay
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call other methods in the controller dynamically but it's not a great idea for various reasons. You can have private controller methods and then call them based on the condition but then your code will not be Object Oriented.

But If you have to do this,

You can use Object#send

```
if @payment.save
    send("pay_with_#{params[:method]}")
end
```

or you can use method.call

```
if @payment.save
    method("pay_with_#{params[:method]}").call
end
```

Having said this, the best way would be to have the pay method is models and call them based on your parameter, probably using STI.